# TFS 2010, cannot get files to workspace, The server returned content type text/html, which is not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I'm getting the TFS error **"The server returned content type text/html, which is not supported"**  while downloading files to workspace. I tried different workspaces and all the time the same error

Because of this error I cannot get all files. Is there any up to date hotfix, solution that can resolve this issue?

I'm using VS 2010 TFS, application written in ASP.NET C# 3.5, SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956824/tfs-2010-the-server-returned-content-type-text-html-which-is-not-supported-err

Comment: Have you installed the recently released TFS 2010 service Pack 1?

Comment: this question without solution, asked 5 months ago.

Comment: I didn't. Do u think it should fix the problem?

Comment: I didn't upgrade. It's a new project I just added it to tfs

Answer (score 0):

I can't say 100% for sure that this fix was included in TFS 2010 SP1 but I believe it was:

[Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2010, Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=43d9f36a-6347-4ac4-86b6-cee4cd54b5d2)

[**Note**: Suggest you take all appropriate backup measures, as you would before making any change to a production environment.]

Comment: Other than installing TFS2010 SP1 which contains a rollup of previous hotfixes, without seeing your project, your TFS setup and its history, No I don't. Do you have a reason for NOT installing TFS 2010 SP1?